# How do I copy the current page URL in IE using Autohotkey?

Tags: internet-explorer, autohotkey

I use F6 and ^{insert} to retrieve the URL. This works fine in Firefox, but fails in IE and Maxthon. Instead, my selection gets copied. If I do it manually, then it works in all browsers. Any workarounds?

```
SendEvent, {F6} 
SendEvent, ^{ins}
Clipwait
URL = %clipboard%
MsgBox, Your browser is: %browser%
MsgBox, URL copied: %URL%
```

Comment: I found the solution. You need to put a delay between the two sendevents. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275405/how-can-i-get-the-current-browser-url-with-an-autohotkey-script for alternative solutions.

Comment: Khalil, please don't add `[Resolved]` to your questions.  Instead, post your own answer below here in the box where it says, `Your Answer`.  You'll get your questions closed if you continue this way - you've done it here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070686/resolvedhow-to-evaluate-function-in-if-else-statement-autohotkey

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the current browser URL with an AutoHotKey script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275405/how-can-i-get-the-current-browser-url-with-an-autohotkey-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a delay between the two sendevents worked for me. It provides enough time for the URL to be selected before the clipboard copy action takes place.